# Comparing Strings in Java without java.lang.String

Tags: java, string, utf-8

java.lang.String class always converts data into an internal UTF-16 representation, and implies always a Charset Decoder pass.

I have UTF-8 strings represented in byte[] objects and I would like to "compare" them without the need of creating java.lang.String objects.
The standard "Collator" class need to convert data to java.lang.String.

I'm running OpenJDK/Oracle Java8

Comment: Can you see if you can use `java.lang.String.String(byte[] bytes, String charsetName) throws UnsupportedEncodingException` constructor instead?

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

Comment: @PavanKumar The OP says that they do not want to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16.

Comment: Seems like the OP does not want `String` object as it uses UTF-16, but if the same works without UTF-16, it should be fine. May be he can confirm.

Comment: @PavanKumar Java string is based on UTF-16. This is *always* true.

Comment: Do you need greater/less than comparison or just equality test?

Comment: Asking for a library is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can try [Stack Exchange Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks. Was not aware of the internals.

Comment: sorry for asking for a "library"

Comment: @RealSkeptic  can you release the 'hold' status on this question as I have removed the "offending" phrase ?

Comment: It will just be closed for another reason (there is no clear question here), or downvoted for lack of research. If you really don't need a library, and are willing to write your own code, you should show the code you wrote as a result of your research efforts, and explain where you ran into an issue with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use java.util.Arrays.equals(pt1[], pt2[]) to compare two arrays. It works with all primitive types.

Comment: I need "greater than", it must check for special Unicode sequences for instance an a raw byte comparison is not useful